# Determine the language of the given NPDA

Tags: pushdown-automata

[image: question]

#### Thoughts

I am wondering is the language $ab^*$, since $a$ pushes $X$ to the stack and $b$ pops, and if there is an $a$ there has to be a $b$ to get back to the final state?

Also, is it right to say $ab^*$ since there is no rule saying that if the top of the stack is $X$ and the input is $a$ I can push another $X$?

Comment: For your second sentence, make sure you understand what the action of $a, \epsilon\rightarrow X$ is.